# how to retrive a file from database using java servlet and jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

i m trying to upload file in database with medium blob data type.it is stored in MySQL db.but i am unable to retrieve that file in appropriate format.i can retrieve that only in bit format.so pl z tell me how to retrieve file from database in exact format.

Comment: look at my post inside of sample answer and exact solution for you problem for that link...

Answer (score 0):

sample code you should change like you code as following:

```
/* Code to retrieve from Blob field */
    String sqlString = 
    "SELECT PLAN_DOCUMENT_NAME,PLAN_DOCUMENT 
     FROM BRS_PLAN_DESCRIPTION 
     WHERE PLAN_ID = ?";

    ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlString);
    ps.setString (1,planId);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
    fileBytes = rs.getBytes("PLAN_DOCUMENT");
    fileName = rs.getString("PLAN_DOCUMENT_NAME");
    }

    brsPlanDocument.setPlanId(planId);
    brsPlanDocument.setFileName(fileName);
    brsPlanDocument.setFileBytes(fileBytes);
```

you should refer this sample links:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/17e8f6/inserting-and-retrieving-images-from-database-using-servlets/